# How to calculate Mardia's multivariate normality in Mplus?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, multivariate-normal-distribution, confirmatory-factor, mplus

I would like to assess the multivariate normality of the structural equation model (SEM) in Mplus. I have a few questions regarding this matter:

1. How can I examine multivariate normality, specifically Mardia's coefficient, in Mplus?
2. Could you provide the current recommended threshold for Mardia's multivariate coefficient? If my recollection is accurate, the kurtosis value should not exceed 3.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, many CFA and SEM experts nowadays think that omnibus tests of multivariate normality are obsolete and/or not typically very helpful for CFA/SEM. Since robust estimation methods (Satorra-Bentler correction and others) are now easily available in most software programs (e.g., MLR, MLM, MLMV estimators in Mplus) and since these robust estimators yield appropriately adjusted standard errors and test statistics under non-normality, it appears that global tests such as Mardia's test are no longer needed.

Quoting Bengt Muthen (https://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/9/352.html):

"My own opinion is that tests of multivariate normality are of less importance now that we have non-normality robust techniques using MLR or MLM in Mplus. Experience indicates that under non-normality the normality-based ML parameter estimates are quite robust, the SEs that MLR and MLM give are very good, and MLR/ MLM chi-square test of model fit is also very good. Normality testing seems to have been advocated in earlier days when these robust techniques hadn't been implemented. So in this sense, the focus on testing normality in the context of latent variable modeling is in my view a bit outdated."

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a multivariate skew and kurtosis test in Mplus by running a CFA or SEM model as a mixture (latent class) model with a single class and requesting TECH13. (A single-class mixture model gives you the same parameter estimates as a regular CFA/SEM model.) Below is a 2-factor CFA example:

TITLE: Fitting a 2-factor model

DATA: file = example.dat;

VARIABLE: NAMES = Y1-Y4;

```
      CLASSES = C(1);
```

ANALYSIS: TYPE = MIXTURE;

MODEL:
%OVERALL%
F1 by Y1 Y2;
F2 by Y3 Y4;

OUTPUT: SAMPSTAT TECH13;

See also: https://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/9/352.html